# Require.js with Backbone.js scope from define()

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I am using backbone.js and require.js

upon initialization of my website with require.js, I do something like:

```
define(["jquery","jqueryMobile","etc","jadajada"]), function($) {

var postList = new HomepagePostList();  

/*  more code */

}
```

I am creating a new instance of HomepagePostList(), which is a backbone collection. I am calling it 'postList'.

Later in the app, I need to access this instance. For example to add some more models.

But I cannot access postList (Reference error, not defined) from other. Tt seems to be only accessible inside the define function.

How can I access postList later in my app, outside the define() function?

Answer (score 1):

return the `postList` and from other files you will be able to use `postList`

```
   define(["jquery","jqueryMobile","etc","jadajada"]), function($) {

    var postList = new HomepagePostList();  

    /*  more code */
    return postList ;
    }
```

Comment: plus be sure u have included HomepagePostList in deps array